# Selecting a spesific date every 3rd month in a DAX formula

Tags: date, dax

Good day

I am battling to get this formula right:
- I have a table with the following columns: Line Nr, Payment Amount, First Payment date, Payment day, Frequency.
[See Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSPnk.png)

What the list is saying is that I am doing a payment every nth month on the same day as the first payment date.
I want to have a DAX formula to only show the "Amount" on the date of payment, based on every nth month in my Pivottable list of dates.

Help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not following completely. Can you mock up what you want your table to look like?

Comment: This looks like a problem to be solved in the import (power query, m-code) or sql, rather then in DAX.